# How to simulate quantum entanglement variation in different quantum gates?

Tags: entanglement, simulation

I'm trying to study quantum entanglement variation during quantum computation with 4 qubit systems comprising a variety of quantum gates.
How can I simulate this variation on MATLAB? Is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Choose a [measure](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/entanglement-measure) for the entanglement. There are [a lot of entanglement measures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/322317/why-are-there-so-many-different-measures-of-entanglement), some of them are easier to calculate in MATLAB than others.

***Step 2:*** Initialize your 4-qubit system's density matrix. It will be a 16x16 matrix since $2^4 = 16$. This means all calculations will be very fast in MATLAB and you will have no problem working with the density matrix rather than wavefunction. You could also work with the wavefunction, but a lot of entanglement measures are defined in terms of the density matrix so it's better to work with the density matrix for this type of thing.

***Step 3:*** Apply your various gates. They will be unitaries, so this will just be some matrix multiplications like: $\rho_{t} = U\rho_{t-1} U^\dagger$, where $\rho_{t-1}$ is the density matrix before the gate is applied, and $\rho_{t}$ is the density matrix after the gate is applied.

***Step 4:*** Calculate the your entanglement measure, which can be a function of the density matrix: $f(\rho_t)$.

***Step 5:*** Now you have $f(\rho_1)$, $f(\rho_2)$, $f(\rho_3) \ldots $
You now have the entanglement measure at each point in time, and you can plot this and see how your measure of etanglement varies over the course of applying all your gates.

Comment: As long as the total state is pure (which seems to be tacitly assumed), there are clearly preferred entanglement measures, most importantly the entropy of entanglement.  Many entanglement measures only really make sense once one looks at mixed states.  Also, it is most easily computed from the pure state vector directly.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, the author of the question said nothing about there being an environment interacting with the 4 qubits. Just that there would be various gates applied. I guess you could still have a mixed state if you ***start*** in a mixed state, but my answer uses the density matrix anyway so it works for both pure and mixed. What are the referred entanglement measures for a pure state of 4 qubits?

Comment: Entropy of entanglement.  Specifically, one desirable property of good entanglement measures is that for pure states, they are equal to the entropy of entanglement, with negativity being the one popular exception (really for its computability - but for pure states, entropy of entanglement is in fact easier to compute than negativity).

Comment: von Neumann or Renyi ? And aren't there other measures apart from entropy of entanglement and negativity?

Comment: Sure there are, but the nice ones usually collapse to the entropy of entanglement for pure states.   Von Neumann, by the way, because it is operationally well defined and pretty much the only way to put *one* number on the entanglement of a pure state.

Comment: There's a guy that once told me that the Renyi entropy is the ONLY one that should be used. Also, what you mean by "nice ones" usually collapse to the entropy of entanglement, is subjective, so I didn't choose an entanglement measure for the OP, I just said they can decide for themselves. If the question was "which entanglement measure sure I use", I would probably have answered differently depending on the details of the OP's problem.

Comment: Plenio and Virmani, https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163, pg 8: *The following is
a list of possible postulates for entanglement measures,
some of which are not satisfied by all proposed quantities: [...] 4. For pure state |psi><psi| the measure reduces to the
entropy of entanglement*

Comment: list of "possible postulates", there is no rigorous fundamental requirement as far as I know.

Comment: Of course not, you can call entanglement measure whatever you please.  But those are the ones people commonly agree on are desirable (even if not always met, e.g. for such pragmatic reasons as computability).  That's all I said.

Comment: Well it should be non-zero for the Bell state right?

Comment: That's number 1. in the list of "possible postulates" in the Plenio-Virmani paper.  In fact, they say log 2.